# How Can I Trigger Edit-Save Process on records through SuitScript?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

We have some scripts triggered by user event-create or update. Could someone tell me how to use suitscript to simulate Edit-Save process on NetSuite records.

The following code doesn't trigger other scripts.

> function triggerScriptTest() {
>       nlapiLogExecution('debug','Start!!!');
>       var record = nlapiLoadRecord('itemfulfillment', 267765);
>       var itemCount = record.getLineItemCount('item');
>       nlapiLogExecution('debug','Number of Items',itemCount);
>       var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(record, true);
>       nlapiLogExecution('debug','Finished!!!');
>   }

Answer (score 3):

This is because a User Event can't trigger other User Events. You can get around this by loading/saving the record within a Suitelet and calling it from your User Event.

Comment: Hi, Adolfo, thanks for letting me know that. Could you tell me how to load/save the record in a suitlet? Appreciate for your help.